# jQuery .each() loop going wild

Tags: jquery, each

I have about 25 groups of div containers with its child container shares the same parent/child class name, also there is an empty div container for each group.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        child content1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="empty"></div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        child content2
    </div>
</div>   
<div class="empty"></div>

.....

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        child content25
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="empty"></div>
```

I want to append each "child" div element to the "empty" div container so it will look like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        child content1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="empty">
    <div class="child">
        child content1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        child content2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="empty">
    <div class="child">
        child content2
    </div>
</div>

....

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        child content25
    </div>
</div>
<div class="empty">
    <div class="child">
        child content25
    </div>
</div>
```

I used following code:

```
$('.parent').each(function(){    
    $(this).find('div').appendTo('.empty');
});
```

But the result shows the "child" div element & its content got looped to the "empty" div 25 times for each group, that's 25x25=625 new "child" divs! It's going wild!!!!!!!!!!!!

Can someone help?!

Comment: `.appendTo('.empty')` matches every `.empty` div, which means you're adding every child div to every `.empty` div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/tf3HM/) looks like what you want:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        child content1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="empty"></div>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        child content2
    </div>
</div>   
<div class="empty"></div>​
```

JS:

```
$('.parent').each(function() {
    var parent= $(this);
    var child = parent.children('.child');
    parent.next('.empty').append(child.clone());
});​
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct I believe. I've edited my answer to follow this implementation as well, thank you.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I can have a nice Thanksgiving now! You too guys! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Might it perhaps work better with .next()?

```
$('.parent').each(function(){   
       var parent = $(this);
       var child = parent.children('.child');
       parent.next('.empty').append(child.clone());
});
```

Here's a fiddle after messing with the implementation a bit -> http://jsfiddle.net/g9G85/8/

Comment: You're right, the previous version didn't work. I've made a few changes, but still haven't tested it thoroughly, sorry.

Comment: Appreciate your effort, all turn out good! Happy Thanksgiving!